# `import =` is not supported webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

After i added babel-loader to my webpack file i started to get this error

```
Please consider using `import <moduleName> from '<moduleName>';` alongside Typescript's --allowSyntheticDefaultImports option.
```

Also in my tsconfig.json file i got the following config

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist/",
"sourceMap": true,
"noImplicitAny": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"target": "es5",
"jsx": "react",
"allowJs": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
}
```

It seems like tsconfig doesn't work, because i already have allowSyntheticDefaultImports on `true`, i think it's just ignored for some reason.
My webpack config is pretty simple

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
mode: "development",

devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.json']
},
devServer: {
    overlay: true
},

output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    publicPath: "/dist"
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "ts-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                "style-loader",
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        modules: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
},
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
};
```

Why my tsconfig file doesn't work? Do i have wrong outDir path?

Comment: I think the error you're getting explains the fix. `import = <some module>` is incorrect. You need to use `import <something> from <module path>`

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7062